# Any free OCR engine or API to identify hand written scan document?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using google Tesseract engine python binder https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/ to extract the text in a image(http://ceoarunachal.nic.in/eci/affidavits/s02/ge/1/KIREN%20RIJIJU/KirenRijiju_SC1.jpg). I am trying to make it digitized for thousands of images similar to it. But Tesseract is not able to extract the handwritten text in it correctly, as its mainly designed for machine text.

Any way to optimize current image which will help in improving the recognition by training the data or is there any other better tools to do it?